# PL/SQL Database values not reflecting correctly to SSIS Scripts

Tags: vba, ssis, plsqldeveloper

I have a table in PL/SQL Developer and this is being used inside SSIS scripts written in VB2008.
Whenever, I make updates on the table, it is not reflecting correctly when retrieving those values on my scripts and keep showing the initial values I have fetched. Not unless I restart my computer, it then start getting the updated values. However, if I make updates on the table again, it won't show the updated values.

I deleted a record, and my script still able to get the deleted record.

```
Dim conn As New OracleConnection
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=blah blah blah.."

        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            conn.Close()
            conn.Open()
        End If
        conn.Open()

        Dim Cmd As New OracleCommand
        Cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
        Cmd.CommandText = "myPLSQLFunctionInsidePackage"
        Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        Cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("output", OracleType.VarChar, 100)).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
        Cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("mydatatype", OracleType.VarChar)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        Cmd.Parameters("mydatatype").Value = vMyDataType
        Cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("mydatacode", OracleType.VarChar)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        Cmd.Parameters("mydatacode").Value = vMyDataCode
        Dim rowCnt As Integer
        rowCnt = Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If rowCnt > 0 Then
            If Cmd.Parameters("output").Value Is DBNull.Value Then
                dataFlag = ""
            Else
                dataFlag = Cmd.Parameters("output").Value
            End If
        End If
        conn.Close()
```

This line of code is the one handling the procedure result:

```
dataFlag = Cmd.Parameters("output").Value
```

My initial value is "WEDNESDAY", then I want to change the schedule to "FRIDAY". So, I do need to update the database. My SSIS got stuck with the WEDNESDAY value, I would get the FRIDAY value if I restart my machine. It should not work like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is now resolved. Just found out that update statements in PL/SQL need to be committed using this code:

```
COMMIT;
```

I'm new to PL/SQL so I didn't know that PL/SQL work this way unlike TSQL that commits automatically your query updates.

Hope this helps to others who are new to PL/SQL.